# How I remove inputted numbers from a Text Area?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, list, textarea

```
/*
 * IntegerSumsView.java
 * This is a program that allows an individual to add a list of numbers, and choose whether 
 * they add all numbers, or only even or odd numbers
 */

   public class IntegerSumsView extends FrameView {

//

int position = 0;
int[] aryInteger = new int[10];

 public IntegerSumsView(SingleFrameApplication app) {
    super(app);

    initComponents();

    // status bar initialization - message timeout, idle icon and busy animation, etc
    ResourceMap resourceMap = getResourceMap();
    int messageTimeout = resourceMap.getInteger("StatusBar.messageTimeout");
    messageTimer = new Timer(messageTimeout, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            statusMessageLabel.setText("");
        }
    });
    messageTimer.setRepeats(false);
    int busyAnimationRate = resourceMap.getInteger("StatusBar.busyAnimationRate");
    for (int i = 0; i < busyIcons.length; i++) {
        busyIcons[i] = resourceMap.getIcon("StatusBar.busyIcons[" + i + "]");
    }
    busyIconTimer = new Timer(busyAnimationRate, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            busyIconIndex = (busyIconIndex + 1) % busyIcons.length;
            statusAnimationLabel.setIcon(busyIcons[busyIconIndex]);
        }
    });
    idleIcon = resourceMap.getIcon("StatusBar.idleIcon");
    statusAnimationLabel.setIcon(idleIcon);
    progressBar.setVisible(false);

    // connecting action tasks to status bar via TaskMonitor
    TaskMonitor taskMonitor = new TaskMonitor(getApplication().getContext());
    taskMonitor.addPropertyChangeListener(new java.beans.PropertyChangeListener() {
        public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            String propertyName = evt.getPropertyName();
            if ("started".equals(propertyName)) {
                if (!busyIconTimer.isRunning()) {
                    statusAnimationLabel.setIcon(busyIcons[0]);
                    busyIconIndex = 0;
                    busyIconTimer.start();
                }
                progressBar.setVisible(true);
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
            } else if ("done".equals(propertyName)) {
                busyIconTimer.stop();
                statusAnimationLabel.setIcon(idleIcon);
                progressBar.setVisible(false);
                progressBar.setValue(0);
            } else if ("message".equals(propertyName)) {
                String text = (String)(evt.getNewValue());
                statusMessageLabel.setText((text == null) ? "" : text);
                messageTimer.restart();
            } else if ("progress".equals(propertyName)) {
                int value = (Integer)(evt.getNewValue());
                progressBar.setVisible(true);
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                progressBar.setValue(value);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Action
public void showAboutBox() {
    if (aboutBox == null) {
        JFrame mainFrame = IntegerSumsApp.getApplication().getMainFrame();
        aboutBox = new IntegerSumsAboutBox(mainFrame);
        aboutBox.setLocationRelativeTo(mainFrame);
    }
    IntegerSumsApp.getApplication().show(aboutBox);
}

/** This method is called from within the constructor to
 * initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
 * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    mainPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    integerLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    enterIntField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    addIntButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    sumAllButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    userOutputField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    sumEvenButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    userOutputArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    sumOddButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    removeIntButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    menuBar = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    javax.swing.JMenu fileMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    javax.swing.JMenuItem exitMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    javax.swing.JMenu helpMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    javax.swing.JMenuItem aboutMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    statusPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    javax.swing.JSeparator statusPanelSeparator = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
    statusMessageLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    statusAnimationLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    progressBar = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();

    org.jdesktop.application.ResourceMap resourceMap = org.jdesktop.application.Application.getInstance(integersums.IntegerSumsApp.class).getContext().getResourceMap(IntegerSumsView.class);
    integerLabel.setText(resourceMap.getString("integerLabel.text")); // NOI18N
    integerLabel.setName("integerLabel"); // NOI18N

    enterIntField.setText(resourceMap.getString("enterIntField.text")); // NOI18N
    enterIntField.setName("enterIntField"); // NOI18N

    addIntButton.setText(resourceMap.getString("addIntButton.text")); // NOI18N
    addIntButton.setName("addIntButton"); // NOI18N
    addIntButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            addIntButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    sumAllButton.setText(resourceMap.getString("sumAllButton.text")); // NOI18N
    sumAllButton.setName("sumAllButton"); // NOI18N
    sumAllButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            sumAllButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    userOutputField.setText(resourceMap.getString("userOutputField.text")); // NOI18N
    userOutputField.setName("userOutputField"); // NOI18N

    sumEvenButton.setText(resourceMap.getString("sumEvenButton.text")); // NOI18N
    sumEvenButton.setName("sumEvenButton"); // NOI18N
    sumEvenButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            sumEvenButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jScrollPane1.setName("jScrollPane1"); // NOI18N

    userOutputArea.setColumns(20);
    userOutputArea.setRows(5);
    userOutputArea.setName("userOutputArea"); // NOI18N
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(userOutputArea);

    sumOddButton.setText(resourceMap.getString("sumOddButton.text")); // NOI18N
    sumOddButton.setName("sumOddButton"); // NOI18N
    sumOddButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            sumOddButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    removeIntButton.setText(resourceMap.getString("removeIntButton.text")); // NOI18N
    removeIntButton.setName("removeIntButton"); // NOI18N
    removeIntButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            removeIntButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout mainPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(mainPanel);
    mainPanel.setLayout(mainPanelLayout);
    mainPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(userOutputField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 372, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(addIntButton)
                                .addGap(89, 89, 89))
                            .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(sumAllButton)
                                .addGap(73, 73, 73))
                            .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(sumEvenButton)
                                .addGap(61, 61, 61))
                            .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(sumOddButton)
                                .addGap(65, 65, 65)))
                        .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(integerLabel)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(removeIntButton)
                                .addComponent(enterIntField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 181, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18))
    );
    mainPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(48, 48, 48)
            .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(integerLabel)
                        .addComponent(enterIntField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                            .addComponent(removeIntButton))
                        .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(addIntButton)
                            .addGap(8, 8, 8)
                            .addComponent(sumAllButton)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(sumEvenButton)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(sumOddButton)))
                    .addGap(19, 19, 19))
                .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 151, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)))
            .addComponent(userOutputField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(17, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    menuBar.setName("menuBar"); // NOI18N

    fileMenu.setText(resourceMap.getString("fileMenu.text")); // NOI18N
    fileMenu.setName("fileMenu"); // NOI18N

    javax.swing.ActionMap actionMap = org.jdesktop.application.Application.getInstance(integersums.IntegerSumsApp.class).getContext().getActionMap(IntegerSumsView.class, this);
    exitMenuItem.setAction(actionMap.get("quit")); // NOI18N
    exitMenuItem.setName("exitMenuItem"); // NOI18N
    fileMenu.add(exitMenuItem);

    menuBar.add(fileMenu);

    helpMenu.setText(resourceMap.getString("helpMenu.text")); // NOI18N
    helpMenu.setName("helpMenu"); // NOI18N

    aboutMenuItem.setAction(actionMap.get("showAboutBox")); // NOI18N
    aboutMenuItem.setName("aboutMenuItem"); // NOI18N
    helpMenu.add(aboutMenuItem);

    menuBar.add(helpMenu);

    statusPanel.setName("statusPanel"); // NOI18N

    statusPanelSeparator.setName("statusPanelSeparator"); // NOI18N

    statusMessageLabel.setName("statusMessageLabel"); // NOI18N

    statusAnimationLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.LEFT);
    statusAnimationLabel.setName("statusAnimationLabel"); // NOI18N

    progressBar.setName("progressBar"); // NOI18N

    javax.swing.GroupLayout statusPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(statusPanel);
    statusPanel.setLayout(statusPanelLayout);
    statusPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        statusPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(statusPanelSeparator, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(statusPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(statusMessageLabel)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 230, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(progressBar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(statusAnimationLabel)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    statusPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        statusPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(statusPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(statusPanelSeparator, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(statusPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(statusMessageLabel)
                .addComponent(statusAnimationLabel)
                .addComponent(progressBar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(3, 3, 3))
    );

    setComponent(mainPanel);
    setMenuBar(menuBar);
    setStatusBar(statusPanel);
}// </editor-fold>

private void addIntButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

    //I apologize if these comments are a little imformal...or doesn't quite make sense, I'm fairly new at this
    //Here, you add any integer into the enterIntField, and after pressing the addIntButton, the integer is inputted into the
    //userOutputArea, 
    //the "null" is for when you go to add a second integer, it does not input both first integer again ( as well as the second integer)
    //you can add up to 10 different variables.
    //Now I would also like to say I apologize if my any of my terminology is wrong...or makes no sense

    aryInteger[position] = Integer.parseInt(enterIntField.getText());
    position ++;

    userOutputArea.setText(null);

    for (int i = 0; i < position; i++) {
        userOutputArea.setText(userOutputArea.getText() + aryInteger[i] + "\n");

    }

}                                            

private void sumAllButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

    //this adds all numbers inputted and outputs it the userOutputField...

    int sumall = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < position; i++)
    {
    sumall += aryInteger[i];
    }

    userOutputField.setText("The sum of all numbers is " + sumall);

}                                            

private void sumEvenButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

    //add all even numbers

    int sumeven = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < position; i++)
    {
        if(aryInteger[i]%2==0) {
        sumeven += aryInteger[i];
        }
    }
    userOutputField.setText("The sum of all even numbers is " + sumeven);

}                                             

private void sumOddButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

    //adds only the odd numbers...

    int sumodd = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < position; i++)
    {
        if(aryInteger[i]%2!=0) {
        sumodd += aryInteger[i];
        }
    }
    userOutputField.setText("The sum of all odd numbers is " + sumodd);

}
```

The problem is just below...

```
private void removeIntButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
```

and here is where I would like to create a 'remove' button that takes out all the      integers that were already inputted in the userOutputArea.
    so the user can start from scratch without having to exit the program and reopen it.

I originally thought it would be "i" because that's what variable/letter was used to add integers below the 'addIntButtonActionPerformed'
       ...but then again perhaps "i" is only underlined because there is no mention of it under the public class? But then what would I add there 
       without messing anything else up? It makes the most sense to me, however...this is but the fifth program I've ever made in java so what I may think has a high chance of being horribly wrong. 
I know this is pathetic, but this honest my best attempt at the moment, I'm still attempting it while I wait for replies. Even a small hint would be greatly appreciated!

```
    aryInteger.remove(i);

}                                               
// 3 5 6 8 9
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JButton addIntButton;
private javax.swing.JTextField enterIntField;
private javax.swing.JLabel integerLabel;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JPanel mainPanel;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar menuBar;
private javax.swing.JProgressBar progressBar;
private javax.swing.JButton removeIntButton;
private javax.swing.JLabel statusAnimationLabel;
private javax.swing.JLabel statusMessageLabel;
private javax.swing.JPanel statusPanel;
private javax.swing.JButton sumAllButton;
private javax.swing.JButton sumEvenButton;
private javax.swing.JButton sumOddButton;
private javax.swing.JTextArea userOutputArea;
private javax.swing.JTextField userOutputField;
// End of variables declaration
```

Comment: Please consider putting a little more effort into your question, perhaps even writing a sentence or two about what the code does and what you're trying to and how it's not working. All you've done is post code with a few scattered comments. The general rule for a good question is to try to put as much effort into writing your question as you'd like a volunteer expend answering it.

Comment: Where is your code attempts for the `remove()` method? You state that you've made attempts to do this, yet you show none. Please show your best attempt and tell us what problems you may be having with it.

Comment: @Black_Baron Please try to narrow down your code sample just to the relevant parts next time. It's often easier for folks to reproduce and help fix whatever issues you're having if you provide a short bit of code that still exhibits that problem for them to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to clear out `JTextArea` type component `userOutputArea`. If I got it right, then this line of code should do it:

```
userOutputArea.setText("");
```

If you meant something else, please clarify your task further.

Comment: Well...I'm seriously laughing out myself for not thinking of that, to think something so simple compared to what I was originally trying to do. I definitely feel like a bit of an idiot now, but hey? What beginner doesn't every now and then? Anyways, Thank you very much!

Comment: Hmm.yes that works to. Do you mind if I ask one more ridiculous question? Why is null avoided?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I was taught to use `NULL` in such case. `JtextArea` inherits `setText` method from `JtextComponent`. This is from the method description: "If the text is **null or empty**, has the effect of simply deleting the old text" [ from here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText(java.lang.String) ] So how is using `NULL` more dangerous then using an empty string?

Comment: I am wrong and you are right. I had always been taught to set it to the empty String so that the text itself is not null, but it defaults to the empty String if set to null. Please let me remove my comment above. I'd up-vote you again if I could, but I can't. I'll have to find another answer of yours to up-vote.